# predict svm in R returns different results with the same imput

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I am using SVM with a very simple example, but the results returned by the predict method are not always the same.

Here is the code I run:

```
library(e1071)
```

## don't do:  r_m(list=ls())

```
x =  c(2,3,3,1,1,2,3  ,   1,1,2,2,3,2,3)
dim(x) <- c(7 ,2)   
y = factor(c(T,T,T,F,F,F,F))

DF <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
model = svm(y ~ x, data = DF,  method = "C-classification", cost = 1, 
             kernel = "linear")

# exactly the same data as x
xtest =     c(2,3,3,1,1,2,3  ,   1,1,2,2,3,2,3) 
dim(xtest) <- c(7 ,2)  

predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest), prob=TRUE)  
predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest),  prob=TRUE)  
predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest),  prob=TRUE)
```

But I have the following output:

```
> predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest), prob=TRUE)  
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
attr(,"probabilities")
  TRUE FALSE
1  0.5   0.5
2  0.5   0.5
3  0.5   0.5
4  0.5   0.5
5  0.5   0.5
6  0.5   0.5
7  0.5   0.5
Levels: FALSE TRUE
> predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest),  prob=TRUE)  
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
attr(,"probabilities")
  TRUE FALSE
1  0.5   0.5
2  0.5   0.5
3  0.5   0.5
4  0.5   0.5
5  0.5   0.5
6  0.5   0.5
7  0.5   0.5
Levels: FALSE TRUE
> predict(model,  newdata = data.frame(x = xtest),  prob=TRUE)
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
attr(,"probabilities")
          TRUE FALSE
1 3.000001e-14     1
2 3.000001e-14     1
3 3.000001e-14     1
4 3.000001e-14     1
5 3.000001e-14     1
6 3.000001e-14     1
7 3.000001e-14     1
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Sometimes it displays the same output 3 times in a row, but sometimes it displays something different as you can see above.

Note: I am using RStudio

Why does it happen? 
Why does the predict method never predicts something coherent?

Comment: Did you try this outside of RStudio?

Comment: I just tried with RGui and could not reproduce the problem.
Maybe it has to do with RStudio workspace.  However I still wonder why the predict method always predict TRUE.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in native R, if I resubmit the `predict...` line enough times (took over 10 goes) - odd as nothing in `e1017:::predict.svm` appears to be stochastic at first glance

Comment: A side note: please don't post "rm(list=ls())" since some poor fool is going to do a global copy/paste of your post  :-(

Comment: I just ran 100 times, R 3.1.0 64bit,  Windows7, latest e1071 package, unable to force an error.

Comment: I tried with another RStudio on my computer at home and I cannot reproduce the problem. Which version of R were you using @GavinKelly ?
At home I have the latest RStudio version (Version 0.98.501) with R-3.0.3. I will check the version of my computer at work tomorrow.

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit) E1071=1.6.3.   I'm now struggling to recreate the error - so it seems very sporadic.  But the reason you're getting always TRUE predictions is you haven't set "prob=TRUE" in your call to `svm` - it needs to be there in the model building.

Comment: Thank you Gavin for pointing out this mistake. Indeed, after setting prob=TRUE that corrected the problem. I am also using the R version 3.0.2 and struggling to recreate the error. It might be because there was this discrepency between the prob=TRUE parameter of the two method calls

Comment: Possible explanation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64403/libsvm-probability-estimates-in-multi-class-problems